# jQuery AJAX/POST not sending data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

So I have this problem for a while now, and I know there are countless questions on this topic, believe me I tried every solution possible but still does not work.

This is the simplest of examples which in my case is not working

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/add-user.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: 'John'},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

That's it.
I always get back an empty array as a response. I tried with `serialize()` for the `data:` but the response is always empty. I get no errors whatsoever, just an empty array when I should get the posted values.

If, for example, in php I try to `echo` some hard-coded variables I get them, but the `$_POST` and `$_GET` don't work.

Any solution or methods of how I can identify the problem ?

Thank you.

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

Ok, so it seems the problem was with .htaccess which rewrites the url and removes the extension. In the network tab indeed the request was moved permanently. Removing the .php extension from the ajax url: solved it. Thank you and sorry for wasting time. Cheers

Comment: try `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. If you get something other than POST, your original post is probably being redirected and you're actually performing a GET, which is why $_POST would be empty.

Comment: did you set dataType:?

Comment: Yeah, you will have to set "dataType:json" like @javaseeker implied

Comment: @MarcB if I echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] I get GET. Why is that ? javaseeker Do you mean type: in the ajax request ?

Comment: @PatBurke I set dataType: 'json' but now I get no response at all.

Comment: I'm no jquery expert, but I have run into this problem when using the ajax function too - what happens when you use the post function? $.post( "ajax/add-user.php", {name: 'John'}, function( data ) {
 console.log( data );
});

Comment: so yes... something is causing your POSt requests to get an http `301` redirect, causing your script to be fetched via GET instead.

Comment: @MarcB Just out of curiosity in php I print_r($_GET) and print_r($_POST). Both return empty. Any solution ?

Comment: because when a browser's POST request is redirected with a 301, it will NOT convert the posted data to a get request instead. The post data is simply lost.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the problem was with .htaccess which rewrites the url and removes the extension. In the network tab indeed the request was moved permanently. Removing the .php extension from the ajax url: solved it. Thank you and sorry for wasting time. Cheers

Comment: @C.Ovidiu: Please add the eventual solution as a self-answer and mark it accepted, for the benefit of future searchers.

Comment: I had a similar problem (my Ajax "method POST" request was always submitted as a GET request). Due to this post I was checking my rewriting rules and figured out that a slash in the end of the URL was causing a redirect not shown in Chrome's Developers Console. THANKS SO MUCH for the hint to look at .htaccess.

Comment: @C.Ovidiu I had live site with ajax request that uses .php extension. Now I want to configure on local. The way you said that remove the .php extension from your request work fine. But I want to request with .php extension. How can I do that?

Answer (score 24):

You need to set the data type as json in ajax call.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/add-user.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType:'json',
  data: {name: 'John'},
  success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
  }
});
```

At the same time verify your backend code(php), whether it can accept `json` data ?

If not, configure the header as below:

**PHP CODE:**

```
/**
 * Send as JSON
 */
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

Happy Coding :

Comment: And or add this to your ajax object: contentType: `"application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Found this question because `method: "POST"` wasn't working. [Per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), `type` should be used for jQuery versions < 1.9.0 instead of `method`. I didn't realize the CMS was using 1.8.2!

Comment: Thanks @LenArt. I've always been use to up-to-date versions on jQuery, but recently working on an old project and couldn't find out why POST wouldn't work.. I needed `type` in this old project too :p

Answer (score 16):

I recently came across this issue but because of other reasons:

1. My POST data was redirected as 301
2. My Server request was GET
3. I did not get my POST data

My reason - I had a url on the server registered as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/folder/path/to/service/
```

But my client was calling:

```
http://mywebsite.com/folder/path/to/service
```

The .htaccess on the server read this as a 301 GET redirect to the correct URL and deleted the POST data.  The simple solution was to **double check the url path**.

@C.Ovidiu, @MarcB - Both of you guys saved me lots of hours in debugging!

Comment: This was my situation, which I never would have come up with on my own, so thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 8):

Why not use [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

```
$.post("ajax/add-user.php",
       {name: 'John'},
       function(response){
           console.log(response);
       }
);
```

Then in your PHP you could save the input like so:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    $name= $_POST["name"];
    file_put_contents("name.txt", $name)
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
}

exit;
```

Comment: `jQuery.ajax` wraps this functionality - the OP is already using this, under the hood

Answer (score 7):

I was having this same problem and the issue turned out to be one of my variables in the `data` object was undefined. For some reason that prevented the post data being sent. Setting the variable to something other than undefined fixed the problem.

Comment: I got this too, but it was't always causing a problem.  Any idea on what's actually going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying many things but I found below working code for me:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST) ) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

This will work if you will try.

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your code and use:

```
$.ajax({url: 'ajax/add-user.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {name: 'John'},
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data){
alert("success");
console.log(data);
},error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);}
});
```

(so you will receive an error & success alert, ensure is html what you receive.those extra parameters will help you to fine-tune your ajax calls. Later play with async true/false)

also, run your program ajax/add-user.php in a new window (type the url) and see what it echoes.Edit the program and force to echo you something "i.e. legendary hello world" and see if your ajax receive the message.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as I replied earlyer the problem was because .htaccess was removing the .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your .htaccess file, close lines with "#" symbol

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]
```