# Passing value through POST on jQuery UI autocomplete result click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, post, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to pass the id value of the selected item to the search.php file using POST. It works fine if I use GET but doesn't work if I use POST.

Here is the code I have:

```
$( function() {
    $( ".search" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/_inc/autocomplete.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            //alert('selected: ' + ui.item.name);
            var id = ui.item.id;
            $.post("/search.php", {"id": id});
            $(location).attr('href', '/search.php');
        }
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        if(item.label == 'No Match Found'){
            return $( "<li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( item.value )
            .appendTo( ul )
            .css("cursor", "default");
        } else {
            return $( "<li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( ("<a>" + item.id + " - " + item.name + "</a>") )
            .appendTo( ul );
        }
    };
});
```

The data source is pulled from database and converted to JSON using PHP.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a big statement.  What's happening? Not happening? Do you get a javascript error? Does the data go to PHP? What if you `var_dump($_POST);` on the PHP AJAX file?

Comment: The data doesn't go to the PHP page. `var_dump($_POST);` gives me `array(0) { }` .. There are no JS errors. @cale_b

Comment: @KumaranS You can use `$_REQUEST` on the server because it will include both the parameters passed from the GET and the POST  - Or decide whether you're using GET or POST. It's not a best practice to use them both

Comment: For fun, what if you change the line to `$.post("/search.php", {id: id});` - *note removing quotes from around `id` property* does anything change? Additionally, right BEFORE that line, what does `alert(id);` display?

Comment: @cale_b the alert does return the id. removing the quotes doesn't change anything still the same. I did a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` gives me 'array(0) { }'

Comment: Well, clearly this should work.  We're now looking at odd / fringe cases, so please read this Q&A (the question has some info in it as well that may be useful), and advise if there's anything useful / helpful there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098791/jquery-ajax-post-not-sending-data-to-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through Q&A suggested in the comment above, I managed to get it to work. jQuery Autocomplete uses GET to pass variables so I had to use a AJAX call to pass the variable instead with html datatype. Here is the code:

```
var id = ui.item.id;

$.ajax({
    url: "/search.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { id: id },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
    }
});
```