# How to pass AWS access credentials from JavaSCript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a JavaScript to authenticate a user using Cognito Federated Service.

I am able to authenticate user and get access credentials :

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
console.log("Access Key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
console.log("Secret Access Key:", AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey);
console.log("Session Token:", AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken);
});
```

How should I pass these credentials to PHP file.function ? Should I pass them in URL itself ?

Comment: maybe you can find something about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098791/jquery-ajax-post-not-sending-data-to-php ?

Comment: Your AWS secret key is available to in-browser JavaScript? That doesn't sound like a good idea… If JavaScript can see it, so can your users. Is this really what Amazon recommends?

Comment: Pass it using ajax and use POST not GET https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/